# Node.js app works properly locally, but 404 errors on Droplet Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express, ubuntu

Using digital ocean droplet, Ubuntu terminal. I have run npm run build, npm install. I am using Vue.js and have installed the 'quick start' project from their documentation: https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#without-build-tools

Called using node app.js ->

```
    var express = require('express')
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    const path = __dirname + '/dist/';
    var app = express();
    var port = 3000;
    
    var fs = require('fs');
    var files = fs.readdirSync(path+"/assets/");
    console.log(typeof files);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(files));
    
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(express.static(path));
    
    
    app.get("/",function(req,res) {
        console.log("Request for /home")
        res.sendFile(path+"index.html");
    });
    
    //Using files variable made at the top to get Vue build files directory
    for (var i=0;i<files.length;i++) {
        app.get(files[i],function(req,res) {
            console.log("Request for an asset")
            res.sendFile(path+"/assets/"+files[i]);
        });
    }
    
    app.listen(port,function() {
        console.log("Server started on port:"+port);
    });
```

index.html (Gets loaded on Droplet and locally correctly)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite App</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index.8ad48088.js"></script>
    <link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/vendor.5c83c58f.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index.f3fa6de6.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Locally, site works. Then, on droplet when visiting site:
[404 errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riF89.png)

Edit: I have also tried using root user instead of nodejs user (nodejs user is recommended by digital ocean for launching pm2) to see if it may be a permission problem. I am fairly new to Ubuntu, let alone the terminal

SOLUTION: nginx needed correct directory for my website assets to be allowed to serve them. Edited under /etc/nginx/sites-available, then nano default. From there edited under server object:

```
server_name hellonode;

    location ^~ /ResposDevelopment/NodeJS\ Server/Respos\ Vue/dist/ {
            gzip_static on;
            expires 12h;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
```

~ = /var/www/html
-Changed location from ~/assets/ to above solved my problem.

Comment: If you only uploaded the dist forlder you should change res.sendFile(path+"index.html"); to simply res.sendFile("index.html");

Comment: Yo also need to change static folder specified as app.use(express.static("public")); where public can be where you uploaded your static assets relational to dist folder or your main folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION: nginx needed correct directory for my website assets to be allowed to serve them. Edited under /etc/nginx/sites-available, then nano default. From there edited under server object:

server_name hellonode;

```
location ^~ /ResposDevelopment/NodeJS\ Server/Respos\ Vue/dist/ {
        gzip_static on;
        expires 12h;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
```

~ = /var/www/html -Changed location from ~/assets/ to above solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks! This solution worked for me as well! Original was 
`location ^~ /assets/`

Then I changed to my project's assets directory 
`location ^~ /home/app/assets/`
and it worked!